# Have label appear with delay in Swift

Tags: swift

I want to have a delay in my tic tac toe game. This is to make it appear as though the AI is thinking. On my label, `thinkingLabel`, I want to display the following string `"Thinking…"` during the delay. After the delay (the AI has made a move), the label should disappear.

Is there a way for the `dispatch_after` sequence I used to execute two functions, my AI turn and the label change, after the delay? Is there a better approach?

Here's the code I used for the delay:

```
checkforWin()
let delay = 1 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)
let time = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(delay))
dispatch_after(time, dispatch_get_current_queue(), {
    self.aiTurn()
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, of course. The block passed to `dispatch_after` can have an arbitrary number of lines:

```
checkforWin()
let delay = 1 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)
let time = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(delay))

dispatch_after(time, dispatch_get_current_queue(), {
  self.aiTurn()
  // more lines here
})
```

However, if you're going to be updating the UI inside your block, remember that all Cocoa UI updates have to occur on the main thread. Your safest bet is to use `dispatch_get_main_queue` instead of `dispatch_get_current_queue`.

Comment: Alright thank you. I changed to the dispatch_get_main_queue. It worked, only I'm still having an issue- the message is printed to the label after the move, and I need it to appear ONLY when the delay is occurring and to disappear once the AI makes its move so that the computer is "thinking". Any ideas?

Comment: Make your label appear before `dispatch_after` and make it disappear on the line after `self.aiTurn()`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can have multiple statements inside the closure (everything within {}).

```
dispatch_after(time, dispatch_get_current_queue(), {
self.aiTurn()
println("another statement")
self.anotherMethod()
})
```

The entire closure will be executed after the delay. If you have a bunch of statements inside the closure it may look cleaner if you use the trailing closure syntax.

```
dispatch_after(time, dispatch_get_current_queue()){
    self.aiTurn()
    println("another statement")
    self.anotherMethod()
}
```

As a side note: do you have any reason for using `dispatch_get_current_queue` instead of `dispatch_get_main_queue`? The former is deprecated and seems to have been removed in beta 3.